# How to use model.predict after PCA transformation in Python?

Tags: transform, pca, predict, dimension

how can I make predictions with my model after use pca transformation and after the model is already trained? I'm a beginner in this world so please let me know if that question doesn't make sense

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=5)
pca.fit(x)
x=pca.transform(x)
```

I tried to predict with my original variables and got a dimension problem obviously, but can't find anywhere how to transform the data that I want to preview into that new format after training the model